# Joomla - using ajax in custom module

Tags: ajax, joomla, module

Requirments: I can't use components and ajax interface (joomla com).
My goal: Send POST data from default.php (mod_x) to helper.php (mod_x). Data is checked checkboxes - using ajax.

How to do this?

1. I know there has to be a method, to do this directly (can someone give me an example), by removing (I know its security risk, but there has to be a way to secure it by hacking joomla)

   defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
2. Is there some way to give a module task - just like you can do using component (controller)? I can't use component myself. How would this be done? Please be explicit.
3. Is there any other possible way? There has to be... I'm ready for some serious brain-storm. Let's get creative, guys.

P.S. To sum it up, I try to find some creative way to not use components, just module to do ajax call from default.php (ajax runs on checked checkbox/s)
I would prefer also an example in code. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Fron Joomla 3.2 if you needed to make an AJAX request in Joomla! from a custom module or plugin, you can build the URL as below.

```
index.php?option=com_ajax&module=your_module_name&method=YourMethodName&format=json
```

Explanation of each parameter

**1. index.php?option=com_ajax** : ALL requests must be routed through com_ajax.

**2. module=your_module_name**: The first part of this is the type of extension you're using. This can either be 'module' or 'plugin'. The second part is the name of the extension. please take care you're not including the prefix 'mod_' or 'plg_', just the name.

**3. method=YourMethodName**: This is the method name that you are trying to call. If you're using this in a module then the method must be appended with 'Ajax'. So, the method represented here will be **YourMethodNameAjax**. If you're using this on a plugin, the method must be prepended with 'onAjax'. So, the method represented here will be **onAjaxYourMethodName**.

Check more at [Joomla doc](https://docs.joomla.org/Using_Joomla_Ajax_Interface)

Comment: Yes, but as I mentione - I can't use any type of component. Ajax_com is a component. What other options do I have?

Comment: Why are you not using component for ajax call?